# Address an int[] array from a class through a different class and is also constructed from a string?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, unity-game-engine

The important bit is the construction of the reference using a string. ie, I need to get access to that int[] from the construction of a string.

For example using "myClass ["int"+myString]" to access myClass.intArray

What am I doing wrong? How can I do this?

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;

 public class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {

 public int[] intArray = new int[3]{1,2,3};
 }

 //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

 using UnityEngine;
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Reflection;

 public class MyOtherClass : MonoBehaviour {
     MyClass myClass;

     void theMethod(string myString){
          myClass = GetComponent<MyClass> ();
```

//-->Error is here://

```
          int[] theArray = myClass.GetType ().GetFields (myClass ["int"+myString]);
```

//--//

```
          theArray[0] = 4;
     }

     void Awake(){ theMethod("Array"); }
 }
```

Comment: Where are you getting error (in which line) and what's the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`GetFields`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx) returns multiple fieldinfo's. [`GetField`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53seyfee(v=vs.110).aspx) returns one [informational class for one field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo(v=vs.110).aspx).

Using this FieldInfo you can retrieve the actual value (as you call it: the address) from your instance. Once retrieved you can use its value:

```
FieldInfo fi = myClass.GetType().GetField("int"+myString); // GetField instead of GetFields.
int[] theArray = (int[])fi.GetValue(myClass);
theArray[0] = 4;
```

Comment: Error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `MyClass'

Comment: You would only get that error if you doing something like `myClass[x]`, which does not occur in my solution.

Comment: Remove `myClass ["int"+myString]` with `"int"+myString`.

Comment: If my answer is working for you, you can click on the gray tick left of my answer under the voting buttons.

Answer (score 1):

```
myClass.GetType ().GetFields ();
```

[returns an Array of FieldInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3(v=vs.110).aspx)-objects.

so you could go like that:

```
var fieldInfo = myClass.GetType().GetFields().Where(f=>f.Name == "int" + myString).First();
```

and then access its value like that:

```
var theArray = fieldInfo.GetValue(myClass) as int[];
theArray[0] = 4;
```

To Omit the Linq-Part, you can also use the `GetField`-method (which is probably what you tried in the first place)

```
var fieldInfo = myClass.GetType().GetField("int" + myString);  // returns single FieldInfo for your field
```

Also note that, since this is not JavaScript, you cannot access your field using the index-Operator like you seem to try in `GetFields(myClass["int" + myString]);`

Comment: This Worked. I'd +1 you if my rep allowed it. Thanks!